# In Ubuntu 18.04 Postman is not opening and not showing in terminal

Tags: 18.04

I have been facing a problem with Postman in Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed it multiple times, but after using it few days it didn't work and not showing its version or anything in terminal.

When I try to enter a command in terminal like:

```
root@user:~# Postman
Postman: command not found
```

When I try to kill process:

```
root@faisal:~# killall _Postman
_Postman: no process found
```

Does anybody have an idea on what is happening? I am new in Ubuntu.

Comment: try all lower case letters `postman`. How did you install it? Check it with `dpkg -l | grep -i postman` and `snap list | grep -i postman'

Answer (score 2):

If postman application does not kill by

```
killall _Postman
```

or

```
killall Postman
```

Then try it by using all lower case letter like the example below:

```
killall postman
```